# How to change QMenu font size

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qmenu, qfont

The code below creates a `Menu` with 5 `Submenus` and 10 `Actions` per each `Submenu`. Even while the `setPointSize` command is applied to the `Submenus` their font seem to be unaffected and it remains to be large. But the `Actions` font is set to a smaller size even while the command is performed on `Submenus` and not the `Actions`. How to change the font size for both the `Submenus` and `Actions`?

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMenu, QApplication
app = QApplication([])

menu = QMenu()
for i in range(5):
    submenu = menu.addMenu('Submenu %04d' % i)
    font = submenu.font()
    font.setPointSize(10)
    submenu.setFont(font)
    for n in range(10):
        action = submenu.addAction('Action %04d' % n)

menu.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must apply the font to all the menu as shown below:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMenu, QApplication
app = QApplication([])

menu = QMenu()
font = menu.font()
font.setPointSize(18)
menu.setFont(font)
for i in range(5):
    submenu = menu.addMenu('Submenu %04d' % i)
    submenu.setFont(font)
    for n in range(10):
        action = submenu.addAction('Action %04d' % n)

menu.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: The only way to set the font globally for all menus that I've found is with stylesheets: `qApp->setStyleSheet("* {font-family: Verdana;}");`
(or specify `QMenu` selector instead of `*` to set the font just for the menus).